# disable form select item if user ist not a developer

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel-8

is there any option to disable select options if user is not a developer

here is my code snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
       <div class="form-group">
              <label for="confirm-password">Permission</label>
              {!! Form::select('roles[]', $roles,[], array('class' => 'form-control user-role')) !!}
      </div>
</div>
```

my output:

- Developer
- Admin
- Standard

So but i want that an admin can only select

- Admin
- Standard

So how can i do that?

Comment: Try use `$_SESSION` to determine the user position and create an if else based on their positions to show out selectable options.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, so just Developer can select right?

maybe u can check ur output first, the code will be like this

```
@if($your_output == 'Developer')
{!! Form::select('roles[]', $roles,[], array('class' => 'form-control user-role')) !!}
@endif
```

Comment: Administrators and developers can currently change a group. However, the administrator should not be able to assign the Delveloper group to a user.